# Lexical scoping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why is 100 being logged here instead of 101?

```
function myFunction() {
   var i=100;
   function f() {
      return i++;
   }
   return f();
};
var X = myFunction();
console.log(X);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/8fqyh/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `f()` returns the value of `i` before it is incremented. Use pre-increment (`++i`) if you want the value after it is incremented.

Also, it's a bit odd to declare `f()` for no other purpose than to immediately call it. I think what you intended was to return a function that increments `i` and returns the new value each time it is called. To achieve this, simply return the function, then call `console.log(X())` to invoke `f()` and log the incremented value:

```
function myFunction() {
   var i=100;
   return function() { return i++; }
};
var X = myFunction();
console.log(X());
```

Comment: Oh, so if I had said return i+1 it would have worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't increment `i` in the process, as it appears you intended.